# A $2^k$ vertices tournament contains a set of at most $k$ vertices that is not dominated

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show that a $2^k$ vertices tournament contains a set of at most $k$ vertices that is **not** dominated.

A **Dominated Set**, as it was defined for us, is a set of vertices $S$ in a tournament $T$ such that there is a vertex $v\in T\setminus S$ such that points at all the vertices in $S$.

I have been trying different things so far, but I believe it is not true. Taking a $2^2$ tournament, one can easily have a $3$ vertices set $S$ which is not dominated. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn’t supposed to be a set of **at least** $k$ vertices that is not dominated?

Comment: Maybe this is what he intended. This is not the first time he makes that kind of typos...All is translated.(The Professor.)

Comment: Do you have any notion about it? Nothing would seem to work.

Comment: I’ve thought about it a little, but so far without any useful result.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove by induction that the statement "every tournament of order $2^k$ contains an undominated set of size $\le k$" is true for all $k\ge1$. (It is false for $k=0$.)

The base case $k=1$ is trivial. For the induction step, consider a tournament $T$ of order $2^{k+1}$. Since the average outdegree in $T$ is $2^k-\frac12$, we can choose a vertex $v$ with outdegree $\ge2^k$ and indegree $\lt2^k$. Thus we can choose a set $V_0\subseteq V(T)\setminus\{v\}$ of size $|V_0|=2^k$ such that every vertex which dominates $\{v\}$ belongs to $V_0$. Applying the induction hypothesis to the subtournament induced by $V_0$, we get a set $X_0\subseteq V_0$ of size $|X_0|\le k$ which is not dominated by any vertex in $V_0$. If we let $X=\{v\}\cup X_0$, then we have $|X|\le k+1$ and $X$ is not dominated by any vertex in $V(T)$.

**A better formulation:**

Every tournament of order at most $a_k=2^{k+1}-2$ contains an undominated set of size $\le k$.

Here $a_k=2^{k+1}-2$ is the solution of the recurrence $a_{k+1}=2a_k+2$ with initial value $a_0=0$. The proof is essentially the same as before: in a tournament of order $\le a_{k+1}$ we can choose a vertex of indegree $\le a_k$.

Comment: I believe you meant "we can choose a vertex v with ***indegree***" meaning you swapped between indegree and outdegree

Comment: can you explain why that the out degree is at least $2^k$ means that v is not dominated?

Comment: I lost you here :Therefore v is not dominated by any vertex in V∖V0. why?

Comment: yes but in the original tournament T, you still got V0 which does dominate v. no?

Comment: so v is dominated in T no?

Comment: we don't look for "a set of at most k vertices that is not dominated"? which means that v can't be in that set?