# in a tournament graph, any $m$ vertices have common winner. find conditions where statement holds.

Tags: graph-theory

given a (arbitrary) tournament with $n$ nodes, I want to find a condition for where the following statement holds:
for any given set of $m$ vertices, there exists a vertex that has won against all $m$ vertices.
(I used the term winning for having an edge from a "winner" to a "loser")

I tried placing upper bounds on $m$ but this isn't enough, because a vertex might win against all other vertices. In such cases, the statement won't hold for even $m=1$.
I believe I should place conditions on the vertices' degrees, but I do not believe an upper bound on the maximum outdegree would suffice.
Edit: I also disproved these upper bounds on $m$: $max(outdeg),max(indeg),min(outdeg),min(indeg)$
I was wondering if I am headed in the right direction or I'm missing details that can make the problem much simpler.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any examples of tournaments where this property holds for $m>1$?

Comment: Assuming $n\ge m$, a **necessary** condition is that $n\ge2^{m+1}-1$, according to the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722185/a-2k-vertices-tournament-contains-a-set-of-at-most-k-vertices-that-is-not-d Do you have some reason to believe that there is a useful **sufficient** condition?

Comment: @JakeBrown For fixed $m$, a sufficently large **random** tournament will have that property with probability approaching $1$.

Comment: @JakeBrown For $m=2$ the probability that a random tournament on $n$ nodes fails to have the property is overestimated by $\binom n2(\frac34)^{n-2}$ which is $\lt1$ when $n=18$ if I calculated correctly. So there is an example with $m=2$ and $n=18$ but I don't know what it is.

Comment: thanks! I believe a sufficient condition exists but I don't believe it could be achieved with conditions on m and n only (because if one vertex has an outdegree of $n-1$ then the statement won't hold for any positive $m$). I think $max(outdeg) - min(outdeg) \geq m$ or something like this might prove sufficient but I havent been able to prove this

Comment: I don't know of any **useful** sufficient condition. A transitive tournament will satisfy max(outdeg)-min(outdeg)=n-1 but won't have the property you want even for m=1.